# Problem Solving Question (Riddle)

Tags: problem-solving

The problem I need to solve is written as the following:

> Four people want to cross a bridge on a very dark night. They all begin on the same side and want to do the crossing as quickly as possible. A maximum of two persons can cross the bridge at one time. Any group that crosses, either 1 or 2 people, must have a flashlight with them. There is only one flashlight. The flashlight must be walked back and forth, it cannot be thrown. Each person walks at a different speed. A pair must walk together at the rate of the slower person’s pace, no one can be carried.
>
> Here is the list of persons and their speed:
>
> - $A$ ~ $1\text{ min}$
> - $B$ ~ $2\text{ min}$
> - $C$ ~ $5\text{ min}$
> - $D$ ~ $10\text{ min}$
>
> What is the least amount of time needed to get all four people across the bridge?

---

**Here's how I solved it:**

Since each person inevitably has to cross the bridge, the only fact we can manipulate is that someone has to come back each time to get the next person.

$A$ and $D$ cross first, then $A$ goes back. $A$ and $B$ cross second, then $A$ goes back. $A$ and $C$ cross third. In total, that gives me $((10+1) + (2+1) + 5)\text{ min}=(11+3+5)\text{ min}=19\text{ min}$.

The T.A. in class, though, said $19$ was an incorrect answer.

Thoughts?

Comment: This would be better on puzzling.stackexchange, a similar question with different constants is http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/287/fastest-way-to-cross-a-river  The point is that you want the two slow ones to cross together, so the second slowest doesn't count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is this:

$$\begin{align}
ABCD&|&0\\
BC&|AD&10\\
ABC&|D&11\\
B&|ACD&16\\
AB&|CD&17\\
&|ABCD&19
\end{align}
$$

whereas you can do this:

$$\begin{align}
ABCD&|&0\\
CD&|AB&2\\
ACD&|B&3\\
A&|BCD&13\\
AB&|CD&15\\
&|ABCD&17
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

AB over for 2, A back for 1, CD over for 10, B back for 2, AB over for 2, total 17.

Answer (score 0):

[TedEx solved this!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7yDmGnA8Hw0)

Not my solution, but this illustrates it.